# Scalable way to add users in Postfix without creating new unix/linux accounts?

Tags: email, postfix, scalability, user-accounts

What is the most scalable way to add new users in `postfix`? I don't necessarily want to create a new user in `/etc/shadow` just for email. I know I can use aliases but this does not solve the issue of creating an entirely new user that has email.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Youre looking to set up a postfix virtual server. This is extremely common, and if you google 'postfix virtual server' plus your distribution name, you'll likely come up with a guide.

But if you want to figure out everything yourself, the setting you want to start with is [virtual_mailbox_maps](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#virtual_mailbox_maps).